# Войти на сайт с разных адресов

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-webforms

Добрый день. 
Нужно реализовать вход на сайт с разных адресов, так, чтобы в зависимости от адреса грузились разный внешний вид главной страницы.

Например у нас есть страница `index.aspx`

Мы заходим с сайта `SomeSite.aspx` и видим синий фон с приветствием "привет Юзер1" и каким то набором контролов.

Если мы заходим с сайта `AnotherSite`, то фон должен быть красный, надпись "привет кто то".

Ну и так далее.

Можете подсказать как это более правильно реализовать?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP Referrer же.

Беглый поиск по MSDN подсказал, что вам нужно [это](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx).